# How to add dates to pm2 error logs?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Is there a way to add timestamps to error logs in .pm2/logs?

I noticed that `pm2 logs` command shows aggregated logs with timestamps, but looking into log files - there are only messages and stacktraces without dates.

[image]

Comment: Is there any solution that adds it only for errors and not for standard logs?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

As per the [pm2 logs official documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#cli), you can use `--time`, which prefixes logs with a standard formatted timestamp.

```
pm2 start app.js --time
```

If you have already created the app, you can update it while restarting the application with:

```
pm2 restart 0 --time
```

Make sure to `pm2 save` afterwards.

Note that you can also use a custom formatter as per [this issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/183) & [this commit](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/commit/57673937d985473a3bf93b34f1659c5c58febdab):

```
pm2 start app.js --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'
```

where `'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'` is any `momentjs` valid format.

Comment: it appears that if you set `--watch` to look for changes you may lose the log-date-format on app reload, getting you back to logging without date: `pm2 start app.js  --log-date-format 'DD-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS'  --watch`. I just noticed that on my development machine. **LE** corrected: only the `pm2 logs` command will skip showing date/time on app refresh.

Comment: Hello, this dose not work for me.I'm using pm2 to manage python script,could you tell me what's the problem? TXU.

Comment: Is there some way to only timestamp the *error* log and not the standard console log?  I am already time stamping everything that goes to console.log.

Answer (score 49):

As per the command line help (`pm2 logs -h`) running `pm2 logs --timestamp` command should add the timestamp to the logs. However it does seem to not affect old logs! Apparently only new logs show up with timestamp.

To fix this issue pass `--log-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"` to pm2 as a param. For example:

```
pm2 start bin/www --log-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"
```

#### Using process.json

I like process.json for starting my app for convenience so my process.json contains the following:

```
{
  "apps" : [
    {
      "name"        : "app",
      "script"      : "bin/www",
      "log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

then I start my app by just running:

```
pm2 start process.json
```

Once done I see the timestamp showing up just by running:`pm2 logs` Notice that I didn't have to specify --timestamp to see the timestamp.

```
app (out): 2016-08-04 13:46 +01:00: My log here
```

A good read: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/

Comment: don't know why but I can only get timestamp for normal log and not for error logs.

Comment: Thanks, adding ""log_date_format" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"" to my ecosystem file did the trick

Answer (score 17):

Wasted 30 mins on this.

---

- Din't work

  - Other answers din't work
  - [Official CLI](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#cli) din't work too:  `pm2 start app.js [OPTIONS]`, ex:  `pm2 start app.js --time`
- Worked

  - [Official Ecosystem file](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#ecosystem) worked great  (procedure is below)

---

- Create an Ecosystem file `pm2-config.js` in your application root (ex: beside `package.json`)

Paste the below contents & save:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "my-app1",
      script: "./index.js",
      time: true,  // <----------------------- This is the key to make it work
      watch: false,
      env: {
        PORT: 4001,
        NODE_ENV: "production",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

- Now create a shell script `start.sh` (OR, batch file, OR, directly run below commands)

Paste the below contents & save:

```
pm2 stop pm2-config.js
pm2 delete pm2-config.js
pm2 start pm2-config.js
```

Comment: More on Ecosystem file: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Answer (score 15):

```
pm2 start app.js --log-date-format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"
```

Comment: The anser could be ok but please add some more description.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 8):

To use standard formated timestamp:

```
pm2 start app.js --time
```

Or if you want to prefix logs with custom formated timestamp:

```
pm2 start app.js --log-date-format <format>
```

Where `<format>` is a [moment display format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) (eg `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z`).

And if your app is already running you can use [`reload`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#reload) for a *0-second-downtime* reload:

```
pm2 reload app.js --time
```

Or

```
pm2 reload app.js --log-date-format <format>
```

Comment: +1 for reload option, the no downtime was great, I manage about 22 processes right now and was able to add timestamps to all logs via `pm2 reload all --time`

Answer (score 6):

I use PM2, but I don't care for the logs that much. Instead I use bunyan, which gives a ton of flexibility for logging. If you npm install it with *--global* you can also use it as a live log viewer:

This won't timestamp your console.log output, though. But If you convert to `log.info()` or any other Bunyan log function you will get nice logging.

To view live pm2 logs with bunyan, just pipe it:

```
pm2 logs | bunyan
```

Comment: The command pm2 logs prefix your logs message, meaning that piping the content to bunyan doesn't work as expected.

There is a closed request for pm2 to implement a raw log format to support the above.

Comment: PM2 has added a --raw flag for the pm2 logs commands enabling the above by using pm2 logs --raw | bunyan. This will be available in the next release.

Answer (score 5):

1. first update the format (make sure server timezone is what you want)

   ```
   pm2 restart 0 --log-date-format "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM Z"
   ```
2. save all processes

   ```
   pm2 save
   ```
3. run these

   ```
   npm i -G pm2 //if not latest  
   pm2 update
   ```

this works and show log in servers time zone other wise time zone will be different

Comment: Thanks for this! Allowed me to add the time logging without recreating each app

Comment: worked for me, I added "pm2 startup" additionally to make it up after restart

Answer (score 3):

For process.yml , follow these example format. It Worked for me

```
 apps:
  - script   : ./SampleApi/app.js
    name     : 'api-proxy-app'
    instances: 2
    exec_mode: cluster
    watch  : true
    log_date_format : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"
```

Sample Log format with DateTime:

```
2019-07-28 13:46 +06:00: channel created for cancel mandate--####################################
2019-07-28 13:46 +06:00: channel created for cancel mandate--####################################
2019-07-28 13:46 +06:00: channel created for exception scenario--####################################
2019-07-28 13:46 +06:00: channel created for create mandate--####################################
2019-07-28 13:46 +06:00: create channel initiated for cancel mandate--------------------->
2019-07-28 13:46 +06:00: create channel initiated for create mandate--------------------->
2019-07-28 13:46 +06:00: create channel initiated for update mandate--------------------->
```

**Using --log-date-format didn't worked for me.**

Answer (score 0):

The date time format has to be in double quotes as below:

```
pm2 restart 0 --log-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z"
```

Using single quotes I got an error:
[PM2][ERROR] Process or Namespace HH:mm not found